# generate object from key array and values array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two arrays,

```
keys: ["idClient", "idProject","price"]
```

and

```
values: [[1,2,123],[1,3, 45],[2,3,10]]
```

Is it posible to transform these two arrays into one object like:

```
[
  {
    "idClient": 1,
    "idProject": 2,
    "price": 123
  },
  {
    "idClient": 1,
    "idProject": 3,
    "price": 45
  },
  {
    "idClient": 2,
    "idProject": 3,
    "price": 10
  }
]
```

I used something like this :

```
keys.reduce((obj, key, index) => ({ ...obj, [key]: values[index] }), {});
```

But it groups values per key, not in the way I want..

```
idClient: (3) [1, 2, 123]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.reduce` function inside `Array.prototype.map` function of `values` and it will work.

```js
const keys = ["idClient", "idProject","price"];
const values = [[1,2,123],[1,3, 45],[2,3,10]];

const output = values.map((item) => item.reduce((acc, curV, curI) => {
  acc[keys[curI]] = curV;
  return acc;
}, {}));
console.log(output);
```