# Object construction from a keys array and values array without the use of loops

Tags: javascript, arrays

This question is extremely similar to:
[generate object from key array and values array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65236097/generate-object-from-key-array-and-values-array)
[Transform array of keys and array of values into array of objects javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633285/transform-array-of-keys-and-array-of-values-into-array-of-objects-javascript)

This question has been answered more than once and might seem like a duplicate. It is possible to construct an object from arrays of keys and values. However, every method for such a construction uses loops or function like `.reduce()` that utilize loops. Deconstructing an object is can be easily done using inbuilt methods `Object.keys()` and `Object.values()` and `Object.entries()`. Constructing an object from key-value pairs is also possible using `Object.fromEntries()`. The issue is that given two arrays, one of keys and another of values, is it possible **without loops** to construct an object.

(Hopefully the sample code below clarify what my complicated question doesn't. PR might not be my strong suit ¯\_(ツ)_/¯)

```js
function constructObject (keys, values)
{
  // ... loopless implementation
}

constructObject(["a", "b", "c", Symbol("d")], [0, null, false, {}]);
/*
// expected output
{
"a" : 0,
"b" : null,
"c" : false,
[Symbol("d")] : {}
}
*/
```

Comment: everything you mentioned is a loop internally i guess

Comment: A low level loop is not as bad as a for loop in js ig

Comment: you are underestimating for loops

Comment: https://youmightnotneed.com/lodash#zipObject

Comment: Still uses a loop but i guess that is inevitable